# What are the differences between a C#(.Net) Compiler and Java Compiler Technologies?

Tags: c#, java

My professor asked us this question: What are the differences between a C#(.Net) Compiler and Java Compiler Technologies?

Comment: Why not ask your university teacher?

Comment: @Shoban SO policy is that questions which can be googled  post here.Please don't discourage.Who knows you will get a point or two in the answers which you don't know of !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the Java and C# compilers compile to an "machine code" for an intermediate virtual machine that is independent of the ultimate execution platform; the JVM and CLR respectively.

JVM was originally designed solely to support Java.  While it is possible to compile languages other than Java to run on a JVM, there are aspects of its design that are not entirely suited to certain classes of language.  By contrast, the CLR and its instruction set were designed from day one to support a range of languages.

Another difference is in the way that JIT compilation works.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp#Runtime_environments), CLR is designed to run fully compiled code, so (presumably) the CLR's JIT compiler must eagerly compile the entire application before starting.  (I also gather that you can compile the bytecodes to native code ahead of time.)  By contrast, the Hotspot JVMs use true "just in time" compilation.  Bytecode methods are initially executed by the JVM using a bytecode interpreter, which also gathers trace information about execution paths taken within the method. Those methods that are executed a number of times then get compiled to native code by the JIT compiler, using the captured trace information to help in the code optimization.  This allows the native code to be optimized for the actual execution platform and even for the behaviour of the current execution of the application.

Of course, the C# and Java languages have many significant differences, and the corresponding compilers are different because of the need to handle these linguistic differences.  For example, some C# compilers do more type inferencing ... because the corresponding C# *language version* relies more on inferred types.  (And note that both the Java and C# *languages* have evolved over time.)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of *compiler*, the largest difference I can think of (except the obvious "inputs" and "outputs") is the generics implementation, since both *have* generics, but **very** different (type erasure vs runtime-assisted). The boxing model is obviously different, but I'm not sure that is huge for the compiler.

The are obvious difference in *features* in terms of anonymous methods, anonymous inner classes, lambdas, delegates, etc but that is hard to compare 1:1. Ultimately, though, only your professor knows the answer he is looking for (and all due respect to professors, but don't *necessarily* be surprised if his answer is a year-or-more out of date with the bleeding edge).

Comment: I think that type erasure is actually more of a codegen issue, and thus the generics implementations in both compilers are likely similar.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that the C# compiler has some type inferencing capabilities that a Java compiler wouldn't have (although Java 7 may change this). As a simple example, in Java you have to type `Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();` while in C# you can use `var anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();` (although you can create very large, complex expressions in C# without ever having to name a type).

Another difference is that the C# compiler can create expression trees, enabling you to pass *descriptions* of a function to another function. For example, `(Func<int,int>) x => x * 2` is a function that takes an int and doubles it, while `(Expression<Func<int,int>>) x => x * 2` is a datastructure that describes a function that takes an int and doubles it. You can take this description and compile it into a function (to run locally) or translate it into SQL (to run as part of a database query).

Comment: really nice exlaination. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

http://www.scribd.com/doc/6256795/Comparison-Between-CLR-and-JVM

i think this will give you an basic idea

Comment: That compares the CLR and the JVM, for Java at least (I am not quite as well versed in .NET, though I would venture that it is largely the same) the compiler is a *very* different and separate beast from the JVM.